# Stored Procedure IF statement in MY SQL returing error 1241

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I am writing this code in MYSQL workbench to check for the data in several tables in order to enter a customer and various customer details in multiple tables without duplication and to gather the primary key for the variable from each table before moving onto the next one. I used the same IF ELSE syntax for an INSERT Statement that worked flawlessly but it is failing with the addition of the SELECT statement in the beginning to check for the customerID in a view and the UPDATE statement at the end instead of INSERTS only.

It's failing with error 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I tried to find the answer to this and found lots of questions about this error but none pertaining to this syntax.

Can anyone help? Code is below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`U03qew`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_modify_customer`(IN CUST_ID INT(11), IN CUST_COUNTRY VARCHAR(50), 
IN CUST_NAME VARCHAR(45), IN CUST_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50), IN CUST_ADDRESS2 VARCHAR(50), IN CUST_CITY VARCHAR(50), 
IN CUST_ZIP VARCHAR(10), IN CUST_PHONE VARCHAR(20), IN CUR_USER VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE ccountryId VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE ccityId VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE caddressId VARCHAR(50);
IF (SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerId = CUST_ID) IS NOT NULL THEN
BEGIN
IF (SELECT countryId FROM country WHERE country = CUST_COUNTRY) IS NOT NULL THEN
BEGIN
SELECT countryId FROM country WHERE country = CUST_COUNTRY
INTO ccountryId;
END;
ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO country (country, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy)
VALUES (CUST_COUNTRY, current_date(), CUR_USER, current_timestamp(), CUR_USER);
SELECT countryId FROM country WHERE country = CUST_COUNTRY
INTO ccountryId;
END;
END IF;
IF (SELECT cityId FROM city WHERE city = CUST_CITY AND countryId = ccountryId) IS NOT NULL THEN
BEGIN
SELECT cityId FROM city WHERE city = CUST_CITY AND countryId = ccountryId
INTO ccityId;
END;
ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO city (city, countryId, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy)
VALUES (CUST_CITY, ccountryId, current_date(), CUR_USER, current_timestamp(), CUR_USER);
SELECT cityId FROM city WHERE city = CUST_CITY AND countryId = ccountryId
INTO ccityId;
END;
END IF;
IF (SELECT addressId FROM address WHERE address = CUST_ADDRESS AND address2 = CUST_ADDRESS2 AND phone = CUST_PHONE AND cityId = ccityId) IS NOT NULL THEN
BEGIN
SELECT addressID FROM address WHERE address = CUST_ADDRESS AND address2 = CUST_ADDRESS2 AND phone = CUST_PHONE AND cityId = ccityID 
INTO caddressId;
END;
ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO address (address, address2, cityId, postalCode, phone, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateby)
VALUES (CUST_ADDRESS, CUST_ADDRESS2, ccityId, CUST_ZIP, CUST_PHONE, current_date(), CUR_USER, current_timestamp(), CUR_USER);
SELECT addressId FROM address WHERE address = CUST_ADDRESS AND address2 = CUST_ADDRESS2 AND phone = CUST_PHONE AND cityId = ccityID 
INTO caddressId;
END;
END IF;
UPDATE customer 
SET customerName = CUST_NAME, addressId = caddressId, active = 1, lastupdate = current_timestamp(), lastUpdateBy = CUR_USER
WHERE customerId = CUST_ID;
END;
ELSE BEGIN
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerId = CUST_ID;
END;
END IF;
END
IF (SELECT cityId FROM city WHERE city = CUST_CITY AND countryId = ccountryId) IS NOT NULL THEN 
BEGIN SELECT cityId FROM city WHERE city = CUST_CITY AND countryId = ccountryId INTO ccityId; 
END; 
ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO city (city, countryId, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy) 
VALUES (CUST_CITY, ccountryId, current_date(), CUR_USER, current_timestamp(), CUR_USER); 
SELECT cityId FROM city WHERE city = CUST_CITY AND countryId = ccountryId INTO ccityId; 
END; 
END IF; 
IF (SELECT addressId FROM address WHERE address = CUST_ADDRESS AND address2 = CUST_ADDRESS2 AND phone = CUST_PHONE AND cityId = ccityId) IS NOT NULL THEN 
BEGIN SELECT addressID FROM address WHERE address = CUST_ADDRESS AND address2 = CUST_ADDRESS2 AND phone = CUST_PHONE AND cityId = ccityID INTO caddressId; 
END; 
ELSE 
BEGIN INSERT INTO address (address, address2, cityId, postalCode, phone, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateby) 
VALUES (CUST_ADDRESS, CUST_ADDRESS2, ccityId, CUST_ZIP, CUST_PHONE, current_date(), CUR_USER, current_timestamp(), CUR_USER); 
SELECT addressId FROM address WHERE address = CUST_ADDRESS AND address2 = CUST_ADDRESS2 AND phone = CUST_PHONE AND cityId = ccityID INTO caddressId; 
END; 
END IF; 
UPDATE customer 
SET customerName = CUST_NAME, addressId = caddressId, active = 1, lastupdate = current_timestamp(), lastUpdateBy = CUR_USER WHERE customerId = CUST_ID; 
END; 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerId = CUST_ID; 
END; 
END IF; 
END
```

Comment: Sorry for the code block. I tried to format it but could not get it to accept more than than what is there.

Comment: I would suggest that you simplify the code and continue simplifying it until the error goes aways (that is, comment out blocks of code).

Comment: Yes trying that now. Any idea on how to display a code block this large on stack overflow? I can't seem to get it to work.

thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited correct a couple of lines that weren't indented. For a code block, all the lines must be indented at least 4 spaces. Or you can just highlight all the lines and hit Command-K (on a Mac) or use the `{}` button on the formatting bar.

Answer (score 1):

To address your error, you should understand that when you use a subquery and compare the result to a single value, the subquery must return a scalar.

The mistake is here:

```
IF (SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerId = CUST_ID) IS NOT NULL THEN
```

How can `SELECT *`, which I assume returns multiple columns, be in an `IS NOT NULL expression? Which of the many columns is tested for null?

SQL does support *tuple comparisons* like this:

```
(column1, column2, column3) = (1, 2, 3)
```

But some comparison operations don't support this format, for example `LIKE` or `IS NOT NULL`. For those, you must use just one column on the left of the comparison.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/scalar-subqueries.html for more details on this.

It would be more clear to use `EXISTS (subquery)` instead of `(subquery) IS NOT NULL`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...) THEN
    ...
```

Then it doesn't matter what you put in the select-list, MySQL will ignore it anyway, since it's only interested in whether one or more rows exist, not what they return.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

---

Besides that error, I have some other comments on your code:

- You don't need so many `BEGIN ... END` blocks. The `IF THEN ELSE END IF` syntax already supports blocks of multiple statements.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html
- Code indentation and formatting is important to help you spot logic mistakes.
- You seem to be using `UPDATE` as if it supports an `ELSE` clause. Maybe you mean "if it matches no rows, then do this other thing"? This is a mistake. There is no such feature for `UPDATE`.

  You might like to use the [ROW_COUNT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) instead, to test
  if the UPDATE changed anything.
- Several times you use `SELECT...INTO` to capture an auto-increment ID that was just generated by a preceding `INSERT`. It would be simpler to do this:

  ```
  SET ccountryId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  ```

  That function always returns the most recently generated auto-increment id, and it's safe to use if there are other concurrent sessions doing their own inserts. See the manual on the [LAST_INSERT_ID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to read about it.

Comment: If there is no customerId that matches CUST_ID would the result not be null? I didn't realize that null applied to only one column. That does make sense though. Thank you! How would I query to say if the select statement returns no rows instead of is not null in that case?

Comment: Wow the rest of your tips are really helpful as well. Thanks.

The last ELSE is actually the ELSE from the first IF. 

What I'm trying to do is say that if the first query returns a result then run all the IF/ELSE statements to add the data and as you pointed out get the autoincrement id/primary key. 

But if it returns no results I just want to run the SELECT statement to return an empty result set I can use in JAVA. That's what the last ELSE statement does.

I guess what I need to figure out is how to check if select statement returns a result since I can't do it with IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Found it. IF NOT EXISTS.... 

Thank you Bill. You pointed me directly to my mistake. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You should use code indentation to keep track of which IF/THEN/ELSE block you're in. And avoid unnecessary BEGIN/END blocks.